# the best way to store quantity in $_SESSION

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have the following function to add products to shopping cart:

```
function AddToCart($pid)

     {  

               $_SESSION['products'][]['product_id'] = $pid;
      }
```

What is the best way to store product quantity to the same array with the product id, since the array after the ['products'] generates automatically I'm confused how can I assign quantity there? Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Something like: `$_SESSION['products'][]['product'] = array('id' => $pid, 'qty' => $quantity);`?

Comment: this way I have more arrays inside the ['product']... I would prefer something like ['products']['$array']['product_id'] and ['products']['$array']['quantity']

Comment: `$_SESSION['products'][][$productid]` is not a good way. You must loop the Array if you add more with the same product id. Why you dont use `$_SESSION['products'][$product_id]['quantity']++`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not store all of the information you need at the same time? Here is an excerpt from my own cart:

```
// add item to cart
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array('product_id' => $product_id,
                            'cat_id' => $cat_id,
                            'title' => $title,
                            'default_img' => $default_img,
                            'price' => $valid_product['base_price'],
                            'weight' => $valid_product['weight'],
                            'length' => $valid_product['length'],
                            'width' => $valid_product['width'],
                            'height' => $valid_product['height'],
                            'surcharge' => $surcharge,
                            'quantity' => $quantity,
                            'prop_selection' => $prop_selection,
                            'po_id' => $po_id,
                            'stock' => $stock,
                            'shipper_id' => $valid_product['shipper_id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, when AddToCart() is called for a $pid that is already in the array, do you just want it to increment a quantity property for that product? Seems to me you just will need to use an associative array for `$_SESSION['products']` instead of a numerically indexed array like you are now:

```
function AddToCart($pid, $quantity=1) {
    if(is_array($_SESSION['products']) && array_key_exists($pid, $_SESSION['products'])) {
        $_SESSION['products'][$pid]['quantity'] += $quantity;
    } else {
         $_SESSION['products'][$pid] = array(
             'product_id' => $pid,
             'quantity' => $quantity
         );
    }
 }
```